# cmake find_package, find_library can locate glfw, but TARGET glfw is false

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, cmakelists-options

my glfw3 was built from source and a FindGLFW.cmake was used to find the library:

```
find_path(
  GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES
  GLFW
  PATHS
  include)

find_library(
  GLFW_LIBRARY
  NAMES
  glfw glfw3 glfw3dll
  PATHS
  lib)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_package_handle_standard_args(GLFW REQUIRED_VARS GLFW_LIBRARY GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I am able to use `find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(xxx glfw3)` in other projects with no build error. However, the statement inside `if(TARGET glfw)` or `if(TARGET glfw3)`  always gives me false result. What could be the reason?

Example:

```
find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
MESSAGE(STATUS "GLFW: ${GLFW_FOUND}")
if(TARGET glfw)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found it")
else()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Not Found")
endif()
target_link_libraries(xxx glfw3)
```

This gives me `GLFW: TRUE` and `Not Found` output, but no build error.

Comment: You are using, not building glfw. i.e. it is not your "target."  `xxx` is your target.

Comment: @wcochran right, I am building `xxx` that uses glfw. Maybe I am not clear in the original question. I was trying to see if cmake can find glfw by first `find_package(GLFW)`, then `if(TARGET glfw)` output something, and finally `target_link_libraries(xxx glfw3)`

Comment: But... why? Did you read the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)? Like first line: `<PackageName>_FOUND will be set to indicate whether the package was found`

Comment: @KamilCuk and `${GLFW_FOUND}`  is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FindGLFW.cmake` file is insufficient. In fact, it shouldn't be needed or exist *at all*. GLFW provides a config package already. Here's how you should build and use *any* well-behaved CMake package:

First, get the sources, build the package, and install it to a local prefix:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw
Cloning into 'glfw'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27050, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 27050 (delta 40), reused 54 (delta 24), pack-reused 26954
Receiving objects: 100% (27050/27050), 13.27 MiB | 2.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (19047/19047), done.
$ cd glfw/
glfw$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B build
...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/glfw/build
glfw$ cmake --build build
...
glfw$ cmake --install build --prefix install
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/lib/libglfw3.a
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/include/GLFW
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake
-- Installing: /path/to/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets-release.cmake
...
```

Then create a folder for your example project and put your CMakeLists.txt in there:

```
glfw$ mkdir ../glfw-test ; cd ../glfw-test
glfw-test$ vim CMakeLists.txt
glfw-test$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(example)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "GLFW: ${glfw3_FOUND}")
if (TARGET glfw)
  message(STATUS "Target exists")
else ()
  message(STATUS "Target does not exist")
endif()
```

Then you can build it and use the `<pkg>_ROOT` variable to tell CMake where to find `glfw3`. If you had the package installed system-wide, you wouldn't need to set this variable.

```
glfw-test$ cmake -S . -B build -Dglfw3_ROOT=/path/to/glfw/install
...
-- GLFW: 1
-- Target exists
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/glfw-test/build
```

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reason?

There is no such target in your cmake configuration named `glfw` nor `glfw3`.

Note that `target_link_libraries(xxx glfw3)` is most probably linking with a library `glfw3` disregarding your `find_package` call. I think you should rather do `target_include_directories(xxx ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})` and `target_link_libraries(xxx ${GLFW_LIBRARY})`.

Comment: However, when glfw was built, there is a target named glfw3: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L301

Comment: Yes there is. ... and? When it __was built__ then there __was__. But it isn't in your cmake configuration, so there isn't. .. and?

Comment: So when I do `find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)`, which runs `find_library( GLFW_LIBRARY NAMES glfw glfw3)`, shouldn't glfw3 automatically be found as a target and then I can link it with `target_link_libraries(xxx glfw3)`?

Comment: @Tim - no, not in the slightest. CMake does not magically create targets. The Find module would have to call `add_library` and set the properties appropriately.

Comment: `find_library` locates a library file on disk and saves a path to that file in a cache variable. Nothing more. Nowhere does it say that `find_library` will create a target.

Comment: @AlexReinking Thanks, looks like I did not correctly understand `find_library`. By calling `add_library` finally solves the problem

Comment: @Tim - technically it "solves" it, but it is not a good solution since glfw provides its own CMake package, which you should absolutely prefer over a hand-rolled find-module. See my answer.